# flex-grow automatic margin for the first element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Let's say I have navigation that uses two flexbox containers. With flex-grow property, navigation stretches to fit the main wrapper (which is of 100% width in this case).

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <div id="main_navigator">
            <a id="main_navigator_logo" src="/"></a>
            <ul id="main_navigator_r1">
                <li>
                    <a class="main_nav_btn">BTN 1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="main_nav_btn">BTN 2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="main_nav_btn">BTN 3</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="main_nav_btn">BTN 4</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div id="main_navigator_s1"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div id="main_navigator_regbox"></div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
#main_navigator {
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
}
#main_navigator_logo {
    width: 416px;
    height: 120px;
    display: block;
    background-color: white;
}
#main_navigator_r1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    margin-top: 0px;
    height: 96px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#main_navigator_r1 li {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
}
#main_navigator_r1 li .main_nav_btn {
    color: white;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: "nexa_bold";
    font-size: 0.8em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#main_navigator_s1 {
    width: 2px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #B28039;
}
#main_navigator_regbox {
    background-color: red;
    width: 50px;
    height: 5px;
}
```

As you can see from the code, there is a main container with flexbox property that contains a logo (`<a>` element) and navigation (`<ul>` element that contains flexbox property).

It can be seen that left margin of the first element remains constantly fixed, so margin (or padding) between logo and element remains the same regardless of scaling, whereas other margins between navigation elements are increasing along with viewport when positively scaled.

You can view the visualization [here](https://jsfiddle.net/w5pL8fvw/1/embedded/result/).

---

Is it possible to make all elements in navigation to have same automatic margin?

I've tried putting the logo in `<ul>` container - but due to some automatic resizing it disappeared (the size of logo should remain static, but right margin should not). Is it possible to wrap logo in the container in this specific way?

Thank you!

Comment: add this `#main_navigator_r1 {padding:0;text-align:center}`

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you, it worked fine. But there's a little problem now, width of `.main_nav_btn` elements are perfectly balanced, but `main_navigator_s1` parent (list) element has bigger width compared to others. Is there any way I can balance that?

Comment: EDIT: fixed them by giving every element inline-block property.

Comment: @ShellRox, consider posting an actual answer with an explanation and working code. That will help people better understand the problem and solution.

Comment: @Michael_B Thanks for your suggestion, posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an automatic margin for the first element, navigator must not have pre-set padding and must have its inline elements centered. In this case:

```
#main_navigator_r1 {
    padding:0;
    text-align:center
}
```

In order to retain equal difference between these list elements, they must all have same display properties, in this case `display: inline-block`:

```
#main_navigator_r1 li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

`flex-basis` property can also be considered for elements with parents of flexbox display properties - if `flex-basis` property is set to `0`, all elements inside the flexbox container will have an equal width - thus equal spacing between them.